# How to locate a hidden div element using Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, hidden

I have recently started working on the `selenium` POC for my project and using I am using `IE browser`. I am trying to click on a drop down box, which apparently lies within a `<div>` tag, however that `div` tag is not visible/ **hidden** on the page load, and only appears in the DOM once its clicked through UI.
How can i locate a hidden `div` and click on that

```html
<DIV class="rfdSelectBox rfdSelectBox_Vista rfdSelectBoxDropDown" id=rfdSubMenu1485730150408 style="WIDTH: 188px; OVERFLOW-Y: auto; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 746px; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 108px; VISIBILITY: hidden" rfdParentID="Skinnedctl00_ChangeGroupPopup_C_ddlCategory11"><UL>
<LI class=rfdSelect_selected unselectable="on">Select</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Direct Reports</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">9 Box</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Group</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Manager Level</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Functional Team</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Job Function</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Indirect/My Lane</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Custom Group</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Functional Team Leader</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">Quartile</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">No Existing Recommendation</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">ALL</LI>
<LI unselectable="on">TeamMate</LI></UL></DIV>
```

I have been trying to search for some solution to this problem and have found some thing as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(add));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(element.findElement(add)).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).moveByOffset( 10, 25 ).click(element.findElement(categoryDropDown)).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

**Note:** Due to some reason `.click()` is not working for me, so i have been using `.sendKeys(keys.Enter)` in place of `.click()`

Comment: What is the element 'add' that you are using as the starting point? Is it the container becoz the div you have mentioned has got some kind of parent attribute 'rfdParentID'.

Comment: Add is one of the buttons on UI which i am trying to click even before i click the drop down, basically the logic which i was trying to implement suggests to click somewhere else on the screen and then go on to click the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has been designed in such a way that it doesn't allow to interact with elements which aren't visible on DOM. It is designed to perform the actions which user can do it manually.

So there are two ways by which you can perform this action:-

1. Perform the steps on UI which makes the element visible and then interact with the same.
2. You can use `JavaScript` to perform the actions with all the elements present in the DOM be it visible/hidden, you can use below code to click on the element.

   `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;`
   `js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`